# Adding layer name and field entry where clause

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am very new to the ArcGIS javascript API. I am creaing a web map using only one query layer in arcmap. If `field 1` is not `null` I want to display x and if `field 1` is `null` I want to display y. I did this previously by creating more than one layer in arcmap.However, I would like to only use this one query layer.

[image: Source code screenshot]

Comment: Please post the code itself, not a screen capture.

Comment: if (layerName === 'DEC_DEI_TESTLAYER'){
                                var decTemplate = new InfoTemplate("AMI Deployment Timeline",
                                        "Area: ${NAMELSAD}</br>Est. Start Date: ${EST_START_DATE}</br>Est. Completion Date: ${EST_COMPLETION_DATE}");
                                feature.setInfoTemplate(decTemplate);
                            }

Comment: I am trying to add a second clause... i.e. if (layerName === 'DEC_DEI_TESTLAYER'  ___AND___ Comments_1 is null) then display x.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the [formatted code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

First thing in your query is that you're using a wrong operator : **and** , js uses `&&` instead of `and` ,

also if you want to check if value is not set either to null or undefined by 
unsing  :

ps : note that you have to mention where you get the field , because it always return undefined !  is field located in the layer attributes ?

`(field !=null && typeof(field) != 'undefined')`

The query should look like :

```
if (layerName === 'DEC_DEI_TESTLAYER' && (field !=null && typeof(field) != 'undefined'))
{ ... };
```

Comment: does this fixe the issue ?